# How to create a thread pool in java ?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

What am I supposed to do if I am asked to create N threads to access N resource , is thread pooling the right solution?

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: See Oracle's Java Tutorials: [Executor Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) and [Thread Pools](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html).

Comment: Read up on Spring [Task Execution and Scheduling](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)

Answer (score 1):

If `N` is fixed, then no need for a thread pool. This is suitable only in the case when you have to create and destroy a lot of threads dynamically (in response to client requests in a server, for instance).